# Modified nodal analysis of a half wave rectifier?

Tags: circuit-analysis, matlab, nodal-analysis

I am trying to solve a halfwave rectifier circuit using the modified nodal analysis algorithm in MATLAB. The MATLAB code is given below. I am not able to see where the flaw is in the approach. I will breifly describe the approach followed by me.

I am using an initial guess of zero voltage across the diode for the initial time step. Within this timestep I am performing iterations to find the actual voltage across the diode. After each of the iterations I change the values of I0 and G0 (the conductance and current source --> equavalent of a diode). The error in voltage across the diode is computed, if it is less than a predefined tolerance value, iteration is stopped and moves on to the next step. In the next time step a new guess (or the values from the previous time step) can be used for finding the voltage across the diode as mentioned before.

The program I have written is not working as expected.

The MNA matrix

```
MNA=[G0         -G0             0;...
     -G0        (1/Res)+G0      1;...
      0          Cap/delt      -1;];
```

RHS vector

```
RHS=[Isrc-I0;...
            +I0;...
            (Cap/delt)*Vpre];
```

and the LHS is evaluated as

```
LHS=MNA\RHS;
```

Entire code is given below

```
function MyFunctionSPICE_diode_series_RC_nw
% written on 11-Apr-2022 to verify the SPICE code
clc;close all;clear;format shortEng;

Cap=1e-9;
Res=50;
freq=5.2e9;
start_time=0; end_time=5e-9;
delt=(1/freq)/100;
Vnode2pre=0;
index=0;
Isat=5e-6; % 5uA
Vth=0.026; % 26 mV
Vdiode=0;
Vdiodepre=Vdiode;
LHS=[0;0;0;];
LHSpre=LHS;
tic;
Idiodepre=Isat*exp(Vdiode/Vth);
G0=(Isat/Vth)*exp(Vdiodepre/Vth);
I0=Idiodepre-G0*Vdiodepre;
   % MNA matrix
    MNA=[G0         -G0             0;...
         -G0        (1/Res)+G0      1;...
          0          Cap/delt      -1;];  
for time=start_time:delt:end_time
    %Vdiodepre=0;    
    
    Isrc=sin(2*pi*freq*time);
 
    tol=1; %tolerance for stopping the iteration
    while(tol>1e-5)
        % RHS vector
        RHS=[Isrc-I0;...
            +I0;...
            (Cap/delt)*Vnode2pre];
        % LHS is the solution vector
        LHS=MNA\RHS;
        Vnode2pre=LHS(2)-0;  
        Vdiode=(LHS(1)-LHS(2));   
        Vdiodepre=Vdiode;
        Idiodepre=Isat*exp(Vdiode/Vth);        
        % G0 and I0 are modified
        G0=(Isat/Vth)*exp(Vdiodepre/Vth);  
        I0=Idiodepre-G0*Vdiodepre; 
        % MNA matrix is updated
        MNA=[G0         -G0             0;...
            -G0         (1/Res)+G0      1;...
            0          Cap/delt         -1;];  
        % computing the tolerance
        tol=sum(abs([LHS(1)-LHSpre(1);LHS(2)-LHSpre(2);]));
        % storing the value of the voltage across diode
        
        LHSpre=LHS;
    end
    
    index=index+1;
    V1(index)=LHS(1);V2(index)=LHS(2);
    end
    toc;
    figure(1),plot(0:delt:end_time,V1);grid on;figure(2),plot(0:delt:end_time,V2);grid on;
    end
```

Can you suggest where I have gone wrong? Thank you.

The schematic for the above problem

[image]

Comment: I tried your code in Octave but it complains about "matrix singular to machine precision". I admit I didn't look too hard, but it looks like you're updating `MNA` inside the `while()` loop, but not `RHS`, and also `LHSpre` is only defined outside the `for()` loop, yet it is used to calculate `tol`.

Comment: RHS is updated using the I0 value. Thanks for pointing to LHSpre.

Comment: I have slightly updated the code, but the situation has not changed.

Comment: Neither did it change for me, I still get singular errors. You haven't provided a schematic, so I can't really know what you're trying to do. Is your load a capacitor, only? If yes, then what is `Res`? If it's part of the load (R||C) then shouldn't your matrix be larger? Or is it the diode's resistance? Have you see [this page](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/tech/node14.html)? Maybe it proves helpful.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I have included the schematic. Pleae have a look at it .

Comment: What I have observed is that the voltage at node 1 (between current source and positive terminal of diode) becomes very large after the first time step. In the second time step the value becomes '326.5208 V 'when the 'LHS=MNA\RHS' is executed.

'LHS={326.5108;1.2075e-4;0.0628}'.  This high vaue of volatge at node 1 and a low voltage at node 2 (betweeen negative terminal of diode and shunt cap & resistor) gives 
 the voltage across the diode as approx ' 326.5107 volts '. This makes 'G0 = Inf ' which makes the matrix singular.

Comment: Goodness, I was hoping I misread the part with the current source. :-) Step back a moment and think what you have there: a current source (especially an idealized one) needs to deliver the prescribed current *no matter the load*. That means that, when the diode is reverse-biased, its ON resistance is (theoretically) infinite, yet the current must reach 1 A. That can only mean that the voltage will be R*I=inf*1. Did you really mean to have a current source, or a voltage source? Not lastly, don't forget that the default diode in LTspice has some zero valued parameters (check the help).

Comment: The generator can't be a "current source" ... why don't use delta equations? Or I missed something ...

Comment: @Antonio51 What are delta equations?

Comment: @mwlab  Ok. In fact, there are the "differential" equations that can be "integrated" numerically (by summation). "Derivative of U" replaced by "delta U", "Derivative of time" replaced by "delta t", etc ... "delta t" is fixed as low as needed, but not too low ...

Comment: @Antonio51 okay, thank you.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen As you rightly pointed out it may be related to the source definition that I have used. Thanks for pointing that out.